# C# Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int

Tags: c#, operators

Error occurs on this line:

xPoint is Int32

randomsize is int

```
xPoint = pictureBox1.Width / 2 - randomsize -  objectPos.getOffset / 10 * randomsize / 192;
```

Here's the function(s) which apparently cause it, can someone explain me why?

```
        public float getSector()
        {
            return (float)Math.Floor(x / 192 + 135);
        }

        public Int32 getOffset ()
        {
            return (Int32)((x / 192) - getSector() + 135) * 192 * 10;
        }
```

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer to help out with rep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getOffset` is a **Method**, and must be called.

```
objectPos.getOffset() / 10
```

*(note the parens after getOffset)*

Without the parens, you are referring to the function, not its value.

If you intend for getOffset to be a property, you need to put in the `get` and `set` keywords.

Answer (score 2):

```
xPoint = pictureBox1.Width / 2 - randomsize -  objectPos.getOffset() / 10 * randomsize / 192;
```